# how to bring movement and rotation vectors of object in the current scene in unity editor

Tags: unity

sometimes in unity i need to zoom to fix the exact position and rotation of an object. but movement and rotation sign of the object always stays on object and i think its pivot of the object.

How can i really bring those movement and rotation signs to simply perform those translations of my object?

thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you asking about how to change where the transform gizmos are drawn? Those are the arrows/handles that appear in the editor that you can click & drag to change an object's transformation.

Comment: @DMGregory sorry about bad english. how can i make those arrows appears on scene when im zooming and and bring them to scene instead of the objects pivot position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude solution is to create a new, empty game object. By default, it will be created at the center of your scene view.

Next, parent the object you want to edit to this new object.

Now, use the new object's transform controls to manipulate the whole thing. (If its controls are off-screen, make sure you switch to pivot instead of object center mode)

When you're done, unparent the object back to its original place in the hierarchy and delete the empty object.

Comment: are you sure its best answer? there is no hot key or something like that to bring arrows to screen? i remmeber it was possible in udk